# How can I check hidden files in the notebook file list?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-datalab

When using gsutil as a magic command, hidden files are not copied by default. So I often use hidden files. But I can not see them on the notebook list.

Of course, if you check with `!ls`, the file actually exists. How do I view hidden files in the notebook file list?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [default behavior of Jupyter](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1532), on which Datalab is based, and it doesn't offer a configuration to change that unfortunately.

As a workaround, can you use `find` and `-exec` to copy only files matching a pattern?

Comment: I just wondered if I could check it in the file list. Thank you for answer.